# Dojo doesn't work in MVC Partial View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, dojo

I have a Partial View:

```
<div id="AgreementBox@(ViewData["UniqueId"])" class="agreement-box">
    <span>
        I read agreement
    </span>
    <a>
        terms of usage
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    require([
    'dojo/dom',
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/ready"],
function (dom@(ViewData["UniqueId"]), checkbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"]), construct@(ViewData["UniqueId"]), ready@(ViewData["UniqueId"])) {
    ready@(ViewData["UniqueId"])(function () {
        agreecheckbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"]).placeAt(dom@(ViewData["UniqueId"]).byId("AgreementBox@(ViewData["UniqueId"])"), "first");
    });
    var agreecheckbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"]) = new checkbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"])(
        {
            id: "IAgreeToTermsOfUse@(ViewData["UniqueId"])",
            name: "iagreetotermsofuse@(ViewData["UniqueId"])",
            class: "i-agree-checkbox",
            checked: false
        });
});
</script>
```

I use this view under every form (every form has an unique id witch I use as ViewData["UniqueId"]):

```
@Html.Partial("../MyPartialView", new ViewDataDictionary { { "UniqueId", "Order" } })
```

When this view appears ones per page it works, but when it appears more, then the checkbox doesn't appear on the page. I don't get any error and in chrome debugger the code works!

Generated output:

```
<div id="AgreementBoxContact" class="agreement-box">
    <span>
        I read agreement
    </span>
    <a>
        terms of usage
    </a>
</div>
<script>
    require([
    'dojo/dom',
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/ready"],
function (domContact, checkboxContact, constructContact, readyContact) {
    readyContact(function () {
        agreecheckboxContact.placeAt(domContact.byId("AgreementBoxContact"), "first");
    });
    var agreecheckboxContact = new checkboxContact(
        {
            id: "IAgreeToTermsOfUseContact",
            name: "iagreetotermsofuseContact",
            class: "i-agree-checkbox",
            checked: false
        });
});
</script>
//
//on the same html page
//
<div id="AgreementBoxOrder" class="agreement-box">
    <span>
        I read agreement
    </span>
    <a>
        terms of usage
    </a>
</div>
<script>
    require([
    'dojo/dom',
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/ready"],
function (domOrder, checkboxOrder, constructOrder, readyOrder) {
    readyOrder(function () {
        agreecheckboxOrder.placeAt(domOrder.byId("AgreementBoxOrder"), "first");
    });
    var agreecheckboxOrder = new checkboxOrder(
        {
            id: "IAgreeToTermsOfUseOrder",
            name: "iagreetotermsofuseOrder",
            class: "i-agree-checkbox",
            checked: false
        });
});
</script>
```

Please help me find why it's happening!

Comment: try to replace ```dojo/ready``` by ```dojo/domReady!```

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same result.

Comment: Not sure to understand how this works. Is it multiple checkbox under one form or one checkbox across multiple form ?

Comment: One checkbox across multiple forms

Comment: could you share the generated output (the final html that browser receives) ?

Comment: I added generated output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer! I still don't know why my previous code didn't work. I changed it a little bit and now it works perfectly!

```
<div id="AgreementBox@(ViewData["UniqueId"])" class="agreement-box">
    <span>
        I read agreement
    </span>
    <a>
        terms of usage
    </a>
</div>
}
<script type='text/javascript'>
    require([
    'dojo/dom',
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/domReady!"],
function (dom@(ViewData["UniqueId"]), Create@(ViewData["UniqueId"])) {
    var checkbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"]) = Create@(ViewData["UniqueId"]).create("input", {
        type: "checkbox",
        id: "IAgreeToTermsOfUse@(ViewData["UniqueId"])",
        name: "iagreetotermsofuse@(ViewData["UniqueId"])",
        class: "i-agree-checkbox"
    });
    Create@(ViewData["UniqueId"]).place(checkbox@(ViewData["UniqueId"]), dom@(ViewData["UniqueId"]).byId("AgreementBox@(ViewData["UniqueId"])"), "first");
});
</script>
```

If anybody will find out why my previous code didn't work, I will be happy to get an answer! I spent nearly a week on this problem and I still don't know why it happened!